# XCode 3 : linking different libraries depending on architecture (cpu type)

Tags: architecture, linker, xcode3.2, conditional-compilation

**EDIT**: This question is probably old it is related to xcode 3.

I'm developing an iPhone app which needed voip support so i added the ARM version of [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org)  libraries. But if I'm using the iPhone simulator i want to link the i386 version of the libraries. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I solved it at last. You need to go to your project setting and select the build tab. After that select a setting that you want to be conditional for example Other Linker Flags and from the little drop-down thingy at the bottom left select "Add build setting condition". Do this as many times as necessary.

[Here](http://www.imagechicken.com/viewpic.php?p=1275985383090911700&x=jpg) is an image to explain it.

Comment: This solution is for XCode 3.

Comment: I asked it almost 2 years ago

Comment: And now the link to the image is broken